# need assetic filter to replace variables in JS oder CSS files

Tags: php, symfony, filter, assetic

I am looking for a simple assetic filter that replaces variables in Javascript files in my symfony app.
I would like to define the variables in my apps config.yml and use $variablename in my JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Return css as a controller response.

```
/**
 * @Route("/style.css")
 */
public function styleAction()
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(/* make your css */);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: not sure if this works as I want the filter to be executed before other filters (like less compiling). Otherwise my PHP Less Compiler might crash if I have placeholders in my LESS files. But thanx for the suggestion.